# creating movie clip instance using class in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop

First of all I want to say that I've just a couple hours experience with AS3.

Now, I have 2 .as files, one of them is `main.as` and the second one is `Ship_.as`

main.as :

```
package{
    import flash .display.*;
   // import Enemy;
    public class main extends MovieClip{
        public function main(){
    var hero:Ship_=new Ship_();
    addChild(hero); // I have to use addChild here also.
        }

    }
}
```

and Ship_.as is :

```
package{
    import flash .display.*;

    public class Ship_ extends MovieClip{
        private var myHero:Ship=new Ship(); // moved inside of class definition

        public function Ship_(){
            addChild(myHero);  // I think I added my movie clip into stage by this.
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my Ship MovieClip :  http://prntscr.com/2pjzdwv

When I test it I get an error which says that "`1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions.`"

If I change `private var myHero:Ship=new Ship();` to `public var myHero:Ship=new Ship();` I get `1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addChild.` error. Is there anyone to help me ?

**EDIT**

To be able to see space movieClip into screen, I have to use two addChild() method as I comment in the code,altough I thought the one inside Ship_ constructor would be enough for that.Could you explain why should I also use `addChild(hero);` ?

Comment: @Panzercrisis gave you proper fix for that. About question `why should I also use addChild(hero);`. It's because creating new Sprite/MovieClip doesn't add it to display list. For that you need to use `addChild`. You are doing this in `Ship_` class, you are creating object and adding it. But in `main` class if you just create `new Ship` but don't add it, why you should see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package{
    import flash .display.*;

    public class Ship_ extends MovieClip{
        private var myHero:Ship=new Ship(); // moved inside of class definition

        public function Ship_(){
            addChild(myHero); // moved inside of contructor
        }
    }
}
```

When you call `addChild()` in `Ship_`, it adds `myHero` to the instance of `Ship_`.  But where is `Ship_'`?  At this point, it's just a variable inside of `Main.main()`, but it hasn't been added or anything.

So what you have is a lot like three boxes, A, B, and C.  At first they're all laid out separtely, without one inside of another.  But then you put Box C into Box B.  But now you just have C inside of B, and A is still off by itself.  So to complete the process, you have to put Box B into Box A, and since C is already inside of B, this will make it where C is ultimately inside of A as weel.

Comment: I've edited my question, could you also look at it ?